# Can a user be tracked from this comment?

Tags: discussion, banning, sock-puppets

On [this blog post](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/#comment-19016), there's the following comment:

> yasin allana says:
>   April 21, 2014 at 7:05 pm
>
> I TOO HAD A SIMILAR BAN PUT ON ME .IN ORDER TO REMOVE THE BAN CREATE ANOTHER ACCOUNT WITH 15 REPUTATION THEN SIMPLY VOTE UP ANSWERS AND QUESTIONS POSTED BY YOUR BANNED ACCOUNT .SIMPLE AS THAT

**Can a user be tracked from this comment?** **CLARIFICATION**: more specifically, can the system track this specific pattern of behavior described here, I didn't imply tracking that specific guy personally based on the data from that website; in part because we won't know the IP and can not sure if name is real).

Don't bother reading the blog post or the rest of the comments... basically people hating on SO and mods.

Comment: This seems like giving a kid detention because he tweeted "I cheated on my math test!" Is it really worth our/SE's time to hunt down a user because of an off-site comment?

Comment: Or are you really worried about _your_ extracurricular activities being found out?

Comment: BUT I WAS SO CAREFUL .YOU WILL NEVER FIND ME OUT .BWAHAHAHA

Comment: While trying to track this specific guy down seems like a futile exercise, an algorithm could be derived from what he says: find   accounts that were created newly and voted on contributions from banned OPs. It could one day be unleashed on the database and wreak terrible havoc

Comment: @Pekka웃 - post that as a suggestion. I like. Also, while you may have tried to be sarcastic, IIRC, most criminal busts are specifically due to a perp bragging to their relatives/buddies/squeezes so it's more truth in television than you thought ;)

Comment: Seems to me like the “vote up answers and questions posted by your banned account” thing would catch the notice of the serial voting reverser thing.

Comment: @icktoofay not necessarily, if it's cleverly done (and plenty of voting for other posts is added to the mix)

Comment: Is this why people [hate us so much](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/)? That blog post is actually pretty funny, as long as you have a sense of humor `;)`

Comment: @Cupcake - I wouldn't necessarily judge the amount of hate by that post. As is the case with any self-selected reviews, strong negative emotions are a lot more likely to be motivated to be expressed in public.

Comment: @Robert - I'm not sure I understand the VTC... "Can a user be tracked from this comment?" is the actual question - coupled with very explicit algo suggestion from Pekka - seems to make it very precisely about "the software that powers the Stack Exchange network". I can re-edit it into a feature-suggestion if it'll make that more explicit.

Comment: @DVK that would probably help improve this post. Also, perhaps make it a little less witch-hunty while you're at it too `;)`

Comment: I'm not sure how a post asking about activity on some other website has any relevance at all here, especially involving a hypothetical.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the site was merely the impetus for asking. I was asking whether someone abusing the rules like this can be caught (I am not making an assumption that a current system can catch them... but am making an assumption that it's algorithmically catcheable, and that they **should** be caught if possible.)

Comment: If I understand the comment, the person is bitching about being question-banned on Stack Overflow.  So......?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the bitching is just flavor. The part that matters is their description of what they did (allegedly, granted). IOW, my question isn't "Waaaah someone's unhappy". It's "Look at what this person claimed to do. It's bad. Can we stop them from doing that bad?"

Comment: Oh, I see.  No, there's no way to know.  We have to catch that kind of behavior ourselves, on our site, with our own tools.  Going on a witch hunt based on what somebody says on some other site feels kinda creepy anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - indubitably. Thus my note about "We can't get their IP from another site".

Comment: FWIW, we already know that some people do this. We wonder how they can be smart enough to figure out how to make sock puppets, but not smart enough to post a decent question.  They are the petty thieves of the world, putting goods under their trench coats because they are too lazy to earn the money to buy them.  They're only hurting themselves anyway, and making life a little miserable for the rest of us.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - humans are weird. That's why I'm a computer geek :)

Comment: ... Weird... clicked on "Move to chat" link and it didn't do anything and reloaded the question. Bug?

Comment: Yeah, I got an error message when I tried that.

Comment: @DVK: "Sometimes compilers are so much more reasonable than people." – [Scott Meyers](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.keyholes/97)

Answer (score 17):

A sock-puppet-finding algorithm could be derived from what he says: find and cull (or flag) accounts that were created newly and voted on contributions from banned OPs.

It could one day be unleashed on the database and retroactively wreak terrible havoc.

Comment: After all, who isn't in favor of terrible havoc?

Comment: @dmckee - Sheakspeare?